# Request to reopen 396905 (Identifying UEFI-capable laptops)

Tags: support, reopen-request

[396905](https://superuser.com/questions/396905/how-to-identify-uefi-capable-laptops-to-buy) was (incorrectly, IMHO) closed because it mistaken for a "what should I buy" thread when in fact it is a completely different "how to identify if a laptop is UEFI-capable from the specs before buying it" thread. Moderator that closed it asked me to edit the question and post a re-open request here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post was reopened by two regulars and a diamond.

Thanks for editing it to make it a better fit!